# What is causing REST API error in Acumatica 2017R2?

Tags: acumatica

I'm receiving the following error when consuming the REST API in Acumatica build 17.207.0029 in my local development environment.

> 500 Internal Server Error
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This exception occurs regardless of which endpoint I try to use. Example endpoints that are failing:

`GET /entity/Default/17.200.001/Customer?$expand=MainContact/Address&$filter=MainContact/Email+eq+'johnny@appleseed.com'&$top=1`

`GET /entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/$adHocSchema`

`GET /entity/Default/17.200.001/Shipment/000001?$expand=Packages`

All of these REST calls worked fine previously. (I'm using Postman to test the calls.) Login/logout POST calls appear to work fine and return a 204 No Content status code as expected.

Things I've tried so far:

- Removed all customizations
- Repaired the database using the Acumatica ERP Configuration application

Any ideas?

Stack trace for reference:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Data.Process.PXScreenProcessor.HackEtwTrace(Boolean s)\r\n   at PX.Data.Process.PXScreenProcessor.Process(String uri, IPrincipal user, AsyncCallback cb, Action`1 initContext)\r\n   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.GetScreenInfoWithoutHttpContext(String screenID)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder..ctor(String version, String name, IMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IEntityMappingKeyService entityMappingKeyService, EntityImpl entity, Func`2 screenInfoGetter, ISystemContract systemContract, Boolean returnFullEntities, PXGraph graph)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetCustomFieldsSchema(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.GetCustomFieldSchemaImpl(Entity entity)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the error that is cause by the .Net framework.

Here is an article on the portal explaining a bit more about this issue:
https://portal.acumatica.com/knowledgebase/known-issue-integrations-schedulers-generic-inquiries-using-odata-may-stop-working-on-2017r2-and-2018r1-versions-after-installing-net-framework-4-7-2-build-or-the-latest-windows-update-which-cont/

But to resume it:

**Root cause**: there is a known issue with compatibility between .Net Framework 4.7.2 build and Acumatica 6.1  (6.10.2515 and older), Acumatica 2017R2 (17.207.0029 and older) and 2018R1 (18.101.0039 and older).

**Solution**: The problem is fixed in the versions  6.10.2613 and higher, 17.208.0034 and higher and 18.102.0048 and higher.

If you have trouble finding your .Net version I would recommend using the method on the following microsoft docs site: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: That's it! My laptop recently performed an automatic Windows update and it must have updated the .Net Framework version. Upgrading to Acumatica version 17.208.0034 solved my issue. Thanks for your help.